Calculating distance and size using Cesium and Parallax
Is there any way to use Cesium engine to calculate distances and object sizes?
I already have:
geographic coordinates for 2 points of view,
pitch and yaw of the 4 sight lines that represents the measurement ( two for each POV ).
I'm able to draw the sight lines but I don't know how to proceed to find intersection points to find distance and size.
Any pure javascript calculations would good too.

